# Openmp parallel loop

Tags: c, openmp

I was wondering if it is possible to apply openmp in the below code. The tricky part is l and p.

```
    int l=0;
    for(j=0; j<len2;++j){
      if(pcons[imask ? j : p[j]] == 1){
        pans[imask ? j : p[j]] = pouts[(imask ? j : p[j]) & amask];
      } else {
        if(imask) pans[j]=pna;
        p[l++] = imask ? j : p[j];
      }
    }
```

Please do let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Comment: Are we supposed to understand what this code does?  It looks too obfuscated for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This short answer is: No, it isn't possible to apply OpenMP to this loop.

This is because the value of `l` in any iteration depends on the code path taken in all previous iterations, and cannot be determined solely from the iteration number (value of `j`).  This effects which index in `p` is changed in the `else` branch of your conditional.

The long answer is still No.

The *really* long answer is Maybe, if the right set of OpenMP clauses and assumptions about ordering of values stored into `p`.  However, given such a simple loop, it is extremely unlikely to be faster than the single threaded version and isn't work the effort required to determine if it could actually work and how to get it to do so if it could.  All those threads writing to consecutive memory addresses will cause lots of cache thrashing, flushing, and reloads.

Of greater help would be to store the common calculation (`imask ? j : p[j]`) in a local variable at the start of each loop.